# pandas dataframe hexbin plot has no xlabel or axis values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, ipython

I am trying to plot a dataframe as hexbin but can't seem to get the xlabel and x-axis values to plot. The dataframe is as follows:

```
szen_df.xs('left', level='pos')
```

[image]

and the plot is as follows:

```
szen_df.xs('left', level='pos').plot(x='szen', y='lat', xlim=(0,90), ylim=(-90,90), kind='hexbin', colormap='Reds' )
```

with result:

[image]

Comment: This works find by me. Perhaps you should post a minimal DataFrame that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Works for me too. Let's have your `pandas` version and your `python` version. See if that gets us anywhere.

Comment: pandas is at 0.16.2 and python at 2.7.

Comment: And what is your matplotlib version?

Comment: matplotlib version is 1.3.1.

Comment: I tried it on a minimal simulated dataframe and it works. Just seems to be the larger dataframe. Would having nan in the dataset have anything to do with this?

Comment: It seems to work if I plot using matplotlib directly instead of through pandas `df.plot()`, but only if I use `df.dropna()`. I suspect that pandas won't work with nan in the dataset. I tried `df.dropna().xs(blabla).plot(blabla)` but won't accept it. I still have the problem that I can't just select the `df..xs('left', level='pos')` values, so still looking for a solution.

Comment: Is there a way to use `dropna()` and something like `xs()` together?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  One possible solution would be new_df = df.dropna().    then  your plot statement with new_df

Comment: I tried the `new_df = df.dropna()` and still doesn't plot the x-axis label and values. No error is printed.

Comment: Same here with `matplotlib` 1.4.3 and Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Are you using IPython Notebook? I think it may cause the issue for me.

Comment: @LevLevitsky yes I am using IPython Notebook.

Comment: I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8653), let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 30):

I'm seeing this problem as well with python 2.7, pandas 0.16.2.dev, and ipython version 3.1.0.

Looking to the [documentation for pandas.DataFrame.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), the only reference to the x labels and ticks being invisible is in the sharex option. So, I manually set sharex=False, and poof, the xlabel and xticks come back.

Clearly this is a bug, but I hope this helps for the time being. I'll add these comments to the bug report that you've already started.

Comment: Still present in 0.18.1, relevant [Issue on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10678)

Comment: STILL present in 1.1.5. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36064

Comment: STILL present in 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same as the issue I had here: [matplotlib scatterplot x axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121584/matplotlib-scatterplot-x-axis-labels)

The workaround which worked was to set the axes explicitly. Just leaving this here for the future :)

Might be connected with https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/12949 , Open as of now (6th of April 17)