# matplotlib scatterplot x axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I'm adding the c option to a scatterplot in matplotlib, the x axis labels dissapear. Here's an example: https://github.com/Kornel/scatterplot-matplotlib/blob/master/Scatter%20plot%20x%20axis%20labels.ipynb

Here's the same example as in the notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


test_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "X": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Y": [5, 4, 2, 1],
        "C": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    })
```

Now compare the result of:

```
test_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="X", y="Y", s=50);
```

[image: here the x axis labels are present]

To:

```
test_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="X", y="Y", c="C");
```

[image]

Where are the x axis labels? Is this a feature I'm missing?

Pandas version: 0.18.1
Matplotlib: 1.5.3
Python: 3.5.2

**EDIT**: **The solution** as pointed out by @Kewl is to call plt.subplots and specify the axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
test_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="X", y="Y", s=50, c="C", cmap="plasma", ax=ax);
```

gives

[image: solved]

P.S. It looks like a jupyter issue, the label is fine when called without a jupyter notebook

Comment: Just to say that I tried to run the same code from a python shell lanched from the anaconda console and I am able to see the "X" label. pd.__version__: 0.19.2 matplotlib.__version__: 2.0.0 Python 3.6.0. Maybe it's just the version of one or more of these packages? If I had the time (or if I were in you), I would try to test it with a new conda (or virtual) env to see if this fixes the problem...

Comment: Also: have you tried running your code only as a notebook (with Jupyter)? If so, I would test it without a notebook, to see if it's not just a matter of the "X" axis not showing up because it has no sufficient space in the notebook frame (just a guess).

Comment: @umbe1987 You're right! It works outside of jupyter. I've tried calling tight_layout but that did not change anything :/ Looks like a jupyter bug to me.

Comment: For me, installing pandas with `conda-forge` channel worked.
`conda install -c conda-forge pandas`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That looks like a strange bug with pandas plotting to me! Here's a way around it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='X', y='Y', c='C', ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel("X")
plt.show()
```

This will give you the graph you expect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You know what's funny? set_xlabel is redundat. Calling plt.subplots does the trick. Please see the updated notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
plt.scatter(x="X", y="Y", c=df.color)
plt.xlabel("X axis label")
plt.ylabel("Y axis label")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda, installing `pandas` with `conda-forge` channel resolves the issue.

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pandas
```

[image: Example Image]