# Pandas missing x tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

When I add `c` to a pandas plot, x tick labels disappear. Does anyone know how to add them back?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'mean': {0: 10,
              1: 16,
              2: 18,
              3: 22,
              4: 30},
     'size': {0: 103, 1: 2509, 2: 41939, 3: 145997, 4: 143530},
     'value': {0: 1.5, 1: 4.5, 2: 7.5, 3: 10.5, 4: 13.5}}
)

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='value', y='mean', s=60, c='size', cmap='RdYlGn')
```

[image]

Tried to manually add x tick labels, but still not working.

```
ax.set_xticks(df['value'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df['value'])
```

Comment: `ax.get_figure().tight_layout()`?

Comment: I have tested the code and I do not have that problem, you could display a code that reproduces the error.

Comment: [paul-h](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) `ax.get_figure().tight_layout()` did not work..

Comment: [eyllanesc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc),  interesting.. Would you please tell me how I should do that? Attach a screenshot of Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Quick fix that works for me: add "sharex=False" to the plot call. Would love an explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, I think this is a bug with pandas plot.  However, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121584/matplotlib-scatterplot-x-axis-labels) shows the following workaround.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'mean': {0: 10,
              1: 16,
              2: 18,
              3: 22,
              4: 30},
     'size': {0: 103, 1: 2509, 2: 41939, 3: 145997, 4: 143530},
     'value': {0: 1.5, 1: 4.5, 2: 7.5, 3: 10.5, 4: 13.5}}
)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='value', y='mean', s=60, c='size', cmap='RdYlGn', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: It works :), but why?

Comment: Yeah it works but someone please explain it.