# x axis labels are missing in a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a Pandas data frame with a date column (in a datetime format) containing 3 years of data. Since it is a lot, I have grouped by month and year and plotted a countplot with matplotlib.

The graph doesn't show my x-axis labels, and also I suspect the results are not accurate (the graph looks different on excel), how can I add the labels? and make sure they are grouped by in the right order?

Here is the relevant code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df['datetime_colummn'].groupby([df.datetime_colummn.dt.year.rename('year'),
         df.datetime_colummn.dt.month.rename('month')]).agg('count').plot(ax=ax)
```

I have tried the solution suggested in the following link: [Pandas missing x tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578976/pandas-missing-x-tick-labels) but it didn't work for me as you see in the code above.

And here is the graph:
[image]

Comment: df['datetime_colummn'].groupby([df.datetime_colummn.dt.year.rename('year'),
         df.datetime_colummn.dt.month.rename('month')])['year',''month].agg('count').plot(ax=ax)

Comment: please try this

Comment: @SRG I tried it and it gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`