# X Axis label is missing on Matplotlib Dataframe Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having a common issue but other advised solutions seem not to work including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121584/matplotlib-scatterplot-x-axis-labels)

The labels[Years] on the X axis are not displaying when the kind used is Line. I'll appreciate someone runs the code and help figure it out.
Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/princeinzion/NigeriaGDPtoPopulation/master/API_NGA_DS2_en_csv_v2_10185307.csv', skiprows=4)

df = data.loc[[620, 1168], '1999':'2017']

df = df.T

dfp = df.pct_change()

dfp = dfp.reset_index()
dfp.columns = ['Years', 'Population', 'GDP']
dfp

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

dfp.plot(kind='line',x='Years',y='GDP', color='red', ax=ax1)
dfp.plot(kind='line',x='Years',y='Population', color='blue', ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Below is the result I get. The Years do not display on the X axis.
[image: Line Chart]

Comment: Your year column is a string. You need to convert it to an int.

Answer (score 3):

Convert year to a datetime data type like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/princeinzion/NigeriaGDPtoPopulation/master/API_NGA_DS2_en_csv_v2_10185307.csv', skiprows=4)

df = data.loc[[620, 1168], '1999':'2017']

df = df.T

dfp = df.pct_change()

dfp = dfp.reset_index()
dfp.columns = ['Years', 'Population', 'GDP']
dfp['Years'] = pd.to_datetime(dfp['Years'])
dfp

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

dfp.plot(kind='line',x='Years',y='GDP', color='red', ax=ax1)
dfp.plot(kind='line',x='Years',y='Population', color='blue', ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your advise worked not entirely. The chart is no longer showing the complete range of years. Any suggestions please