# matplotlib plt not setting xlabel/ylabel correctly on scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I am creating a geoplot and trying to set my xlabels and ylabels. It only shows the ylabel, but not the xlabel. Here's a minimal reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = {
    'College': ['East Los Angeles College', 'Santa Monica Ccollege', 'American River College', 'Santa Ana College', 'Mount San Antonio College'],
    'Total Enrollment': [36606, 29999, 29701, 28698, 28481], 
    'Latitude': [34.0414, 34.0166, 38.6511, 33.7580, 34.0482],
    'Longitude': [-118.1503, -118.4704, -121.3467, -117.8889, 117.8451]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='Longitude', y='Latitude',
                     s=df['Total Enrollment']/100, label='Enrollment',
                     c='Total Enrollment', cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"),
                     colorbar=True, alpha=0.5, figsize=(15,12))

plt.ylabel("Latitude", fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Longitude", fontsize=14)

plt.legend(fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How did you create the image you included in your post? Is this the image you get via `plt.savefig(..)`?

Comment: I actually just took a screen capture of the output from my jupyter notebook

Comment: Actually seems like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121584/matplotlib-scatterplot-x-axis-labels

Comment: Maybe also add `plt.tight_layout()`?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for that link, sorry about the duplicate question. I must have missed it while I was looking around.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following lines seems to work for me:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
...
df.plot.scatter(..., ax=ax)

ax.set_ylabel("Latitude", fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude", fontsize=14)
```

Though as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121584/matplotlib-scatterplot-x-axis-labels), calling `plt.subplots` and specifying the axes seems to be the missing link.