# Make pandas plot() show xlabel and xvalues

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using the standard `pandas.df.plot()` function to plot two columns in a dataframe. For some reason, the x-axis values and the xlabel are not visible! There seem to be no options to turn them on in the function either (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Does someone know what is going on, and how to correct it?

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd

ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='t', y='hlReference', c='STEP_STRENGTH', cmap=cm.autumn);
```

gives this:
[image: xvalues and label missing]

Comment: `ax1.set_xlabel('This is my x label')` Further docs are available here: https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#axis-limits

Comment: What about `ax1.set_xlabel()` as found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel) and `set_xticks()` as found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks)

Comment: You would also want `ax1.set_xticklabels()`

Comment: We would probably need to see what `df` is in order to understand why it's actually happening. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidG, I did not provide any data because I felt that the problem was with `df.plot()`. And indeed, it turned out to be so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug with Jupyter notebooks displaying pandas scatterplots that have a colorscale displayed while using Matplotlib as the plotting backend.

@june-skeeter has a solution in the answers that works. Alternatively, pass `sharex=False` to df.plot.scatter and you don't need to create subplots.

```py
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd

X = np.random.rand(10,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['t','hlReference', 'STEP_STRENGTH'])

df.plot.scatter(
    x='t', 
    y='hlReference', 
    c='STEP_STRENGTH', 
    cmap=cm.autumn,
    sharex=False
)
```

See discussion in [this closed pandas issues](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10611#issuecomment-151267698). Which references the above solution in a [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31633381/4590385).

Still an issue with pandas v1.1.0. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36064

Comment: Seems to be an issue in the Spyder IDE as well? Is that because it's running a Jupyter notebook somewhere in the background?

Answer (score 5):

Create your axes instance first and then send it as an argument to the plot()

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd


X = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['t','hlReference', 'STEP_STRENGTH'])
fig,ax1=plt.subplots()
df.plot.scatter(x='t', y='hlReference', c='STEP_STRENGTH', cmap=cm.autumn,ax=ax1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Is this just a simple bug in `df.plot()`?

Comment: I don't think this shows the solution to the problem, simply because if you leave out `fig,ax1=plt.subplots()` and use `df.plot.scatter(x='t', y='hlReference', c='STEP_STRENGTH', cmap=cm.autumn)` it works equally well. This shows how important it is to provide a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: Well this does appear to be an issue. If I follow along with their document examples for [Visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot) `In [64]: df.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', c='c', s=50);` does not give me the x-labels as they have.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If I comment out 'fig,ax1=plt.subplots()' and run 'import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd


X = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['t','hlReference', 'STEP_STRENGTH'])
# fig,ax1=plt.subplots()
df.plot.scatter(x='t', y='hlReference', c='STEP_STRENGTH', cmap=cm.autumn)#ax=ax1)' it doesn't produce the desired result for me?

Comment: I arrived at this question from a bug report in the pandas development forum.
They wrote that this bug only applies for JUPYTER NOTEBOOK with the inline command, not when running Python with a regular IDE.