# Index labels are not displaying - Pandas(Series)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas and matplotlib and I am trying to set the label on x axis by the **index in Series of panda**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index = ['apples','oranges','cherries','bananas']
quantity = [20,30,40,50]

s = pd.Series(quantity, index = index)
s.plot()
plt.title("pandas series")
plt.show()
```

[image: Output Graph]

and it displays the output without the label on the x axis, 
I need fruits name as label on X-axis.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Since there is no intrinsic ordering to your x-values, you probably shouldn't be using a lineplot. If you do `s.plot(kind='bar')` then the labels will show properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some problem with pandas (currently?) as also seen from [Make pandas plot() show xlabel and xvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631031/make-pandas-plot-show-xlabel-and-xvalues).

Here using matplotlib directly is a good option as well. Just replace `s.plot()` by

```
plt.plot(s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just have to define the locations. Do it like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index = ['apples','oranges','cherries','bananas']
quantity = [20,30,40,50]

s = pd.Series(quantity, index = index)
s.plot()
plt.title("pandas series")
plt.xticks(np.arange(4), index) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't really make sense to use a line plot here, since the categories are independent.

try a bar plot, which will automatically include the labels.
`s.plot(kind='bar')`

￼