# Unable to set xlabel when when Pandas creates scatter plot in multiple subplots with color label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis-labels, graphing

I'm unable to set the `xlabel` of plots when

- I use Pandas to make `scatter` plots
- inside multiple subplots
- and specifying the `c` color attribute column.

For example, this works fine: I can see the `xlabel`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
plt.ion()

foo = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5), columns='a b c d e'.split())

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', ax=ax1)
foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='c', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel('xxx')  # works
```

However, the following slight twist, where I set the color `c` field, does not set the `xlabel`:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', ax=ax1, c='c')
foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='c', ax=ax2, c='c')
ax2.set_xlabel('xx')  # NO x label
```

`plt.xlabel` doesn't work either. `ax2.get_xlabel()` returns the `"xx"` that I expect, but it's not visible:

[image: no x label]

How can I get an xlabel in this case? Pandas Github repo has 3000+ open issues, rather than filing this as a bug, I'd rather find a Matplotlib-oriented workaround to render an xlabel. (Python 3.8.1, Pandas 1.0.3, Matplotlib 3.2.0.)

Edit: moved from numeric column names to textual column names since it was causing confusion.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney please note per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html `c` should be a column name. If it's an array-like object, Pandas treats them as a sequence of colors. My usage of `c` works fine in the non-subplot case, i.e., it produces allows me to set xlabels no problem. The subplot is what's causing the issue.

Comment: Not sure where exactly the bug is, but you can use matplotlib instead of pandas (i.e. replace `foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', ax=ax1, c='c')` by `ax1.scatter(x='a', y='b', c='c', data=foo)`)

Comment: Here is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631031/make-pandas-plot-show-xlabel-and-xvalues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visibility of the xlabel is being set to `False` for some reason, to get around it you simply need to do

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', ax=ax1, c='c')
foo.plot.scatter(x='a', y='c', ax=ax2, c='c')
ax2.set_xlabel('xxx')
ax2.xaxis.get_label().set_visible(True)
```

This will give you

[image]

Comment: And the final piece to get it to show xticklabels: `ax2.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=True, labelbottom=True)`. Thank you!